# How to send consumable events through jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

is there any possibility to sent over a consumable one-time event when navigating to another (unrelated and therefore not sharing the same `viewmodel`) screen in `jetpack compose navigation`? When handing over an argument via `navigation`, this value is not being consumed and therefore still present when navigating back and forth between different screens always re-triggering this event.

Do you know an elegant way to archive this? I want to avoid having something like a `SharedFlow` on `Activity` level and every Screen to collect it or to use `SharedPrefs` / `DataStore` to temporarely store those events.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please add the code in question?

Comment: Hi Stelios, just simple „navigate from Screen A to B“. My question is, how could one add a consumable event / parameter to a navigation action in Jetpack Compose Navigation. Normal navigation parameter added to the route will stay there / are not consumed. Thank you very much.